# bootstrap select picker not working with input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **select picker** and I need to make that, when select language from this select picker gets a value from select and put into input filed.

The problem is that when i get value is success but after get show alert empty. and put value empty in field.

```
$(".m_selectpicker").selectpicker();

    $(document).on('change', '.changeLanguage', function () {
            var selectedLanguage = $(this).val();
            alert(selectedLanguage);
            $(this).parents('.countries').find('.lang').attr('name', 'name' + '[' + selectedLanguage + ']');
    });
```

language
             
                  
                       English
                       Arabic
                       Turkey

Comment: you need to change `value` attribute instead of `name`

Comment: check this codepen https://codepen.io/Akhil_dev/pen/eXgJMJ

Comment: Thanks, but after update, as you can see show alert empty and put empty, this error show when i use $(".m_selectpicker").selectpicker();

Answer (score 0):

You can update the value attribute as well, see here https://jsfiddle.net/Lq2fz7dg/

```
 $(document).on('change', '.changeLanguage', function () {
            var selectedLanguage = $(this).val();
            alert(selectedLanguage);
            $(this).parents('.countries').find('.lang').attr('name', 'name' + '[' + selectedLanguage + ']');
            $(this).parents('.countries').find('.lang').attr('value', selectedLanguage);
        });
```

**Update**

This will work when `.selectpicker()` is initialized:

```
$(".m_selectpicker").on("changed.bs.select", 
      function(e, clickedIndex, newValue, oldValue) {
    $('.lang').attr('name', 'name' + '[' + this.value + ']');
            $('.lang').attr('value', this.value);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/no0r3qjf/

Comment: Thanks, but after update, as you can see show alert empty and put empty, this error show when i use $(".m_selectpicker").selectpicker();

Comment: iam sorry not working because you remove class changeLanguage iam clone all dive (select and input) but after clone not working second div.

Comment: this problem when change lang from select one change all, and when change from second or third not working.